# Html title attribute not working after double clicking span element

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the sample code i have used

```
<span title="hello">Hello</span>
```

In normal mouse over, the title attribute working fine.

But after double clicking span element (The text will be highlighted), title attribute not displaying.

Comment: You need to move away, the cursor after highlighting and again hover over the text. Let me know if you are doing that or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's the default behavior of `title` attribute. The text will be shown on hover as a `tooltip`, not on click. It would be better if you will use custom tooltips javascript library like

- https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs
- http://www.tippedjs.com/